# How to execute a Window Batch File on HTML?

Tags: batch-file

When I execute or Launch the .bat file on my HTML link it gives me a Java Virtual Machine Launcher Error: "Could not find the main class:com.cronlo.toptv.installer.finder.InstallerFinder. Program will exit."

I tried to google and I tried everything, I even tried to convert bat to exe hoping that it will work...but no luck...

Please help :-(

Answer (score 0):

I depends on web browser. Basically you must set proper application to handle selected MIME type. If you use Firefox read this [article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) about MIME types handling.

Comment: Thanx Jethro, I'm using IE and this batch file is in the Intranet server and we are all using IE in the company, but when I click on the link it looks like it's executing and then it gives me that error: "Could not find main class: ....."